# Maximum power transfer theorem

Tags: capacitor, ac, inductor, parallel, electrical

[image: Question in a mock test]

Im very stuck on where to go with this question.
The examples in class used complex numbers, where as this doesn't seem to need them.
Im aware that Zs = Zl, but does Zl=Cl+Rl?
Any help with how to approach this question would be great

Comment: What makes you think you don't need complex numbers? How are you going to calculate impedance without them?

Comment: Tiredness and stupidity, I'll give it a go using my brain this time. Thank you

Comment: Have you seen an example of how to convert from a series-reactive circuit to a parallel-reactive circuit? I think that is needed.

Comment: Perhaps your misunderstanding is in Rs=Rl. It is actually Zs=Zl* (complex conjugate)

Comment: If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information here. Do not create a duplicate question.